# Can a website (on chrome) detect if screen mirroring is turned on in windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, mirroring, screensharing, miracast

Or is it possible for any web browser in general to detect if screen is being duplicated on another display? Also Can a web browser know that the OS is begin run inside a virtual box?

Answer (score -2):

Yes In chrome ,the screen mirroring on another display can be detected.
Refer :
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display

Comment: The API you showed is just for ChromeOS